# The language of afterlife

Tags: eschatology, akhirah

I am wondering what will be the language after life? I couldn't find anything anywhere so asking it here.

Is there any ayah or hadith related to what will be language after life?

Answer (score 1):

There is no **Ayah** from Quraan or **Hadieth** from Sunnah say anything about that, So just Allah Knows that, and it is not useful thing to know!!

The useful thing to know is Allah will judge all people, so we should have to work for that day !

Answer (score -1):

It was narrated by al-Tabaraani in al-Awsat, al-Haakim, al-Bayhaqi in Shu’ab al-Eemaan and others that Ibn ‘Abbaas (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Love the Arabs for three reasons, because I am an Arab, the Qur’aan is Arabic and the speech of the people of Paradise is Arabic.”

But dont be too sure, this hadith is very weak

Comment: Can you provide link to hadith.